# date_select ruby issue while populating db value in 'view'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having issues in populating `date` value from my DB to the Rails `View` object. What I have in the DB is a table `License` with an attribute `license_expiration="2012-11-11"`. I need to populate this value in the `View` when the user selects 'edit'. What I have in the **edit.html.erb** file is:

```
<h1>Edit License</h1>
<% product_options_for_selector = options_for_select(product_selection_options, 
@license.product ? @license.product.id : product_selection_options.first.last) 
%>

<% form_tag("/licenses/#{@license.id}", :method => :put, :id => "edit_license_#        @license.id}") do %>
.
.
.
.
<%= label_tag :license_expiration, 'License Expiration:' %> <br />
<%= date_select :license_expiration, @license.license_expiration %>
. 
.
.
```

However, the date_select always default to current date instead of the `@license.license_expiration` value from the DB. Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong here? Help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

--- J.A.N.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try that?

```
<%= date_select :license_expiration, :license_expiration, :default => Time.parse(@license.license_expiration) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond Antoine, appreciate it.

Comment: This means that basically, I need to use the the "default" option to get the 'date'. Why does the regular expression not work? I am a newbie with ruby/rail and so trying to better understand it. Thanks,

Comment: The other comment did not go through. I tried your solution, but that did not work. It generated a "NoMethodError" with the following exception during parsing: "undefined method `gsub!' for Fri, 19 Oct 2012:Date" However, when I removed the 'Time.parse' from the same, everything seems to work fine. I am able to retrieve the "date" correctly from the DB to the 'view' page. Thanks,